# .NET Framework Upgrades and Installations

Tags: windows, installation, .net

This is a 2 part question regarding installing and updating .NET on a server.

1. I have a server with .NET 4.5 installed.  I would like to update it to have .NET 4.5.2.  If I install [this package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643), will I also be able to run apps that target 4.5.1?  Or do I have to install a separate package for .NET 4.5.1?
2. The server does not have .NET 4.6 installed and I like to be able to target both .NET 4.6 and .NET 4.6.1.  Can I simply install [this package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643) to get both versions, or do I have to install them separately?  Or even better, will this package get me the latest 4.5.2 and 4.6.1 versions in 1 shot?

It just seems like there are a lot of options here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx).

> All of the .NET Framework versions listed in the following table are
>   in-place updates to the .NET Framework 4. In other words, if you
>   install a later version, such as the .NET Framework 4.6, you do not
>   first have to install the previous versions, such as the .NET
>   Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, or 4.5.2.

All post-4.0 releases are cumulative; you just need to install the latest one.